# js function not working on ios

Tags: jquery, ios

I have the following code that is not working on ios:

Something inside "paginationCustomRender" is wrong but i can't figure it out.

Is working well from desktop and android

```js
var swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-h', {
  pagination: '.swiper-pagination-h',
  paginationClickable: true,
  spaceBetween: 4,
  keyboardControl: true,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  loop: true,
  speed: 450,
  centeredSlides: true,
  grabCursor: false,
  nextButton: '.h-next',
  prevButton: '.h-prev',
  preventClicks: false,
  preventClicksPropagation: false,
  simulateTouch: false,
  pagination: '.pag-shoes',
  paginationType: "custom",
  paginationCustomRender: function(swiper, current, total) {
    var names = [];
    $(".swiper-slide-ratio").each(function(i) {
      names.push($(this).data("name"));
    });
    var text = "<span>";
    for (let i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
      if (current == i) {
        text += "<span>" + names[i] + "</span>";
      }
    }
    text += "</span>";
    return text;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps ES6 syntax is not supported? Change `let` to `var`

Also arrays start at 0, so names[i] is out of scope when i==total

If current is 1-based use

```
for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  if (current == (i+1)) {
    text += "<span>" + names[i] + "</span>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain or give a better answer

Comment: that's strange... I'm begginer so I can't even vote yet.. and you helped me a lot! :)

Comment: I did not mean you- someone really could help by explaining why